Vulnerability in my Flask API - jwt-extended
A cyber security specialist recently went through my Flask api to see how vulnerable it was and it turns out it was very vulnerable. He was able to retrieve my flask secret key and then view all the sessions and login as an admin and anything else he really wanted to do. He was able to act as admin and get information of all our users.
My question is how exactly he was able to do this. My flask secret key is stored as an environment variable in the server hosting service. Is it a problem with how im generating the access tokens?
The following is my login logic. Keep in mind I am using flask-jwt-extended.
@auth_bp.route("/flask/auth/login", methods=["POST"])
def login():
    data, invalid_request = check_json_and_validate_schema(
        request, login_user_schema)
    if invalid_request:
        return jsonify({"Error": invalid_request}), 422

    email, password = (data["email"], data["password"])
    email = email.lower()
    user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()

    if user is None:
        return jsonify({"error": "user not found"}), 401
    if not bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, password):
        login_data = {}
        login_data["user_id"] = user.user_id
        login_data["is_successful"] = False
        login_log = LoginLog(**login_data)
        db.session.add(login_log)
        db.session.commit()
        return jsonify({"error": "incorrect email or password."}), 401

    login_data = {}
    login_data["user_id"] = user.user_id
    login_data["is_successful"] = True
    login_log = LoginLog(**login_data)
    db.session.add(login_log)
    db.session.commit()


    access_token = create_access_token(identity=user.user_id)
    refresh_token = create_refresh_token(identity=user.user_id)

    resp = jsonify(
        {
            "Message": f"Successfully logged in basic user {user.first_name}",
            "user": user.serialize(),
            "email": user.email,
            "watched_intro": user.watched_intro,
            "access_token": access_token,
            "refresh_token": refresh_token}
    )

    return resp, 200

And this is the relevant part of my config.py file
import os
from datetime import timedelta

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))


class Config(object):
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "postgresql://{0}:{1}@{2}/{3}".format(
        os.getenv("DB_USER"),
        os.getenv("DB_PASS"),
        os.getenv("DB_URL"),
        os.getenv("DB_NAME"),
    )
    CSRF_ENABLED = True
    SECRET_KEY = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY")
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = True
    JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRES = timedelta(days=100)
    JWT_COOKIE_SECURE = True
    JWT_COOKIE_SAMESITE = "None"
    JWT_TOKEN_LOCATION = "headers"
    JWT_CSRF_IN_COOKIES = True
    JWT_COOKIE_CSRF_PROTECT = True
    JWT_ACCESS_CSRF_HEADER_NAME = "X-Csrf-Token"

Any help would be amazing since this is a rather serious security issue. Thank you!

You should never store security details in environment variables, as they are easy to access. You should keep them, suitably encrypted, in a database, that can only be accessed by logging in with a strong password.

Why can't you ask the cyber security specialist? Shouldn't it be part of their work, how they got access?

It can be from any api without login api that a token can get data for another users. You must review all api. Example: api forget password, token to change password for another account

@OldBoy That makes no sense whatsoever. In a proper production setup, environment variables aren't meant to be accessed by anyone but the application itself. They can't be "easily accessed" where it matters, granted that they are set up properly.

It is porbably due to the server or where the app is stored. If root access enabled, you should disable it. And if possible to use some sort of vault, you can keep your sensitive information there. Also you should only accept https requests. If its possible use containers. Do not forget to use @jwt_required() for your resources aswell.

This is not an answer to the question asked.
